# How to hide visibility of forms through drop down

Tags: flutter, dart

How to disable other fields when selecting one from drop down. I have a YES/NO drop down values
the NO should hide the visibility of all the forms that exists

```html
  Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child:DropDownWidget(
                                list: ["Yes","No"],
                                data: patientConsent,
                                hint: getTranslated(context, "select"),
                                heading: getTranslated(context, "patient_consent"),

                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        
                         CustomFromField(
                          heading: getTranslated(context, "sample_id")

                        -----
```

Comment: You can use some global variables to perform validations on your widgets based on value selected using a `setState()`.

Comment: @Ragu Can you elaborate it through  code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic as per your request.

Step :

1. `setState()` is called to update the UI accordingly.
2. Maintain a global variable that could be used inside the build function for validations.

Overview :

```
//... create state codes
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool _value = false;
..
..
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
.. ..
DropdownButton(
..
onChanged: (bool value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value = value;
                        });
                      })

 if (_value) Text('Shown when selected true in dropdown'),
}
}
```

Working snippet can be found [here](https://dartpad.dev/daa6a2044b306ebcbc290cb8443500a2). Let me know for any queries.